# chromium is unresponsive when loading from autostart (Raspian Bullseye)

Tags: localhost, chromium, raspberry-pi4, autostart

I am launching chromium from the autostart and it will not load anything, not a localhost page or even an external page.

The browser window does launch, but it just sits there with "Loading" in the tab title area. Eventually it pops up with the "Page Unresponsive". If I click "Wait" it continues to load with no response. If I click "Exit" I get the Aw Snap, error 5 message, and if I click reload or F5 then it will finally load.

Starting the browser from the menu works without any problems

This is Raspbian Bullseye with all updates, and no other modifications other than to install Apache and PHP.
here is the autostart from /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi

```
#default
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
#added
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
unclutter -display :0 -noevents -grab
@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars http://localhost/loadPlayer.php
```

Comment: this appears to be being discussed at the raspberry pi forums: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1988646

Comment: Thank you!

Looks like it won't load http vs. https.  I am using localhost, so this is a bit of a problem. I assume I can install a self signed cert but I haven't tried that.

for now my workaround has been to install firefox-esr which works fine

Comment: There seems to be a workaround. I'll have to try it out. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1988646#p1989845 https://github.com/RPi-Distro/chromium-browser/issues/28